# UITableViewWrapperView has a leading and trailing margin with super view on tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I'm creating a tableview on tvOS. The `UITableViewWrapperView` is subview of `UITableView` and there is a leading and trailing padding between them. How can I remove these paddings? Thanks?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it with the following setup:

```
tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = false
tableView.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
tableView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
```

Note, remember the tvOS guidelines recommends at least 90px spacing for left and right, and 60px spacing for top and bottom.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/visual-design/layout/

Answer (score 0):

tvOS table views have a lot of weird quirks. I haven't been able to find a clean solution to this for awhile. For now I've been adding negative constraints to the table view cells.