# Apple TV - set tableviewcell position

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, tvos, apple-tv

I have a button inside a custom tableviewcell defined inside a storyboard.
Is it possible to have the label stick to the left? 
Currently it has some space on the left. Please help.

Comment: Try anchoring the leading to the superview and not the superview's default margin.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931488/2108547

Answer (score 0):

In the `attribute inspector` of your `UIButton`:

Change Horizontal Alignment from center:

[image]

to leading :

[image]

**Update:**

Change `Separator Inset` in `UITableView` in storyboard from `Automatic`:

[image]

to `Custom` with left and right value 0 :

[image]

Comment: This did not help @amit. Is this for tvOS specifically?