# Apple TV tvOS - Tableviewcell extra space on left and right side

Tags: swift, uitableview, tvos, apple-tv

I have an app on appletv where i need to design a side menu which sticks to the left side margin without having any spacing. Currently when i drag a tableviewcell on the storyboard, there is a space which comes by default on either sides. That space is the content view's space. How do i remove that space and have the tableview cell stick to the left?
I tried with a custom tableview cell too and the same thing happens. Please help.

Comment: not seeing how you have things setup my initial guess would be you have a constraint which is adding a constant space value.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931488/2108547