# Overriding Margin between UITableView and Custom Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, tvos

I have a UITableView created in code as such:

```
 lazy var tableView:UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = false
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tv
}
```

I am constraining it to the parent view:

```
private func setup() {
    tableView.register(LiveTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

The cusom cell here has nothing but a red background. As rendered, the cell is showing 90 points from the left side of the screen where the tableview starts. I have tried to use `layoutMargins` as well as `contentInset` to no effect. If I do something like: `print(self.tableView.layoutMargins)` it shows that the left margin is indeed 90.

The only way I have been able to overcome this behavior is to add the following: `tv.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: -180, bottom: 0, trailing: -90)` I loath this solution as it relies on magic numbers.

Net, how can I remove this 90 points of left margin without the above hack fix?

More code has been asked for so I am including the tableview delegate and datasource functions below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.liveArray.first?.shows.count ?? 0
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LiveTVCell

    if !self.fetchedRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
        self.fetchedRows.append(indexPath.row)
        self.spinner.start()
        MediaFeedController.retrieveShows(showIDs: liveArray.first!.shows,forSection:indexPath.row) { [unowned self](row) in
            self.spinner.stop()
            guard row != nil else {return}
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row!, section: 0)], with: .none)
            }
        }
    }

    cell.showID = liveArray.first!.shows[indexPath.row]
    //print(self.tableView.layoutMargins)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
```

Here is the tableviewcell. Keep in mind that the issue occurs if I remove all of this from the tableviewcell and just set a background color:

```
import UIKit

class LiveTVCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var showID:Int! {
    didSet {
        setup()
    }
}

private var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

func setup() {


    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "collectionView")
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true
    collectionView.register(ChannelCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "channelCell")
    collectionView.register(ProgramCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "programCell")

    self.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

// MARK: - Collectionview Delegate & Datasource

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let channelCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "channelCell", for: indexPath) as! ChannelCVCell
        channelCell.showID = showID
        return channelCell
    } else {
        let programCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "programCell", for: indexPath) as! ProgramCVCell
        programCell.showID = showID
        return programCell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: 177, height: 70)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 70)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    if section == 0 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    } else {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}

// MARK: - CollectionView Focus Delegates

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    //guard let index = context.nextFocusedIndexPath?.row else {return}
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.collectionView.removeFromSuperview()
}

}
```

Update:

You can completely remove the custom cell and have nothing in `cellForRowAt` and return a generic `UITableViewCell` and the table's layout margin on the left is 90. In fact the second you add the table to the subview and anchor it, it's 90.

Comment: Are you able to provide more code? The code above looks fine to me, maybe its something else

Comment: You can add one more view to tableView cell (set your components in this view) and set leading and trailing constraint (like padding). It is hackable technique but it's works. Enjoy.

Comment: In my actual implementation I have a collectionview within each row (that is anchored to the left/right of the cell). To simplify I removed all of that and just used a custom cell with a red background and the problem persisted.

Comment: You're not showing enough code.

Comment: A lot more code added.

Comment: This is due to a bug in tvOS. I've never found an elegant solution for it. Setting negative constraints is the only solution for now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931488/2108547

Comment: Thank you @DanielStorm for sharing your experience. I have actually launched a help ticket with Apple on this one some days ago. It will be interesting to see if they confirm the bug. I will post back here with that what they come back with. For now the NSDirectionalEdgeInsets is the solution I am working with.